# Unable to identify characters in mysql entries (for search and replace)

Tags: mysql, regex

## Explanation

1. I imported 8000 html docs as posts and custom fields in wordpress.
2. The custom fields are specific links that are in the html documents mentioned.
3. Because of poor formatting, on a bunch of said links contain large amounts of white space in the middle of the link text.
4. During the import, the mysql entry for the custom field retains the white space.
5. Wordpress outputs the white space as break tags, give my links a strange formatting with a lot of space between the text.

## Example

[image]

## Attempted

I've tried to search and replace all 
, 
 tags in these fields. No results found. Understandable because they don't seem to exist in the actual entry.

I think I might need to search and replace line breaks (/r/n) but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this.

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE( meta_value, '\r\n', '' ) WHERE meta_key = 'resource_link'
```

returned 0 results.

Long story short, I need a way to target this white space so I can remove it. Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: Any filters modifying your outputs? Filters can be set by any plugin or the active theme.

Comment: Looks like WordPress is converting `\r\n` to `<br />`. Check your filters.

Comment: yes! I tracked it down to Advanced Custom Fields plugin. If I call the custom field using the ACF function the_field(), it turns line breaks into html tags, whereas if I call it using WPs get_post_meta function, it does not render the <br> tags. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

Advanced custom fields is the culprit here. ACF applies a filter to convert line breaks in mysql to 
 tags. If I call the custom field using get_post_meta, the 
 tags are not applied. Thanks Luceos and SpikeX for the hints.